# Agregar Apple Id a Visual Studio 2019 para mac

Tags: xcode, xamarin, macos, visual-studio-2019

Acabo de instalar VisualStudio 2019 para Mac, Xcode y fastlane, así que todo está en su última versión. Necesito compilar un proyecto en Xamarin para IOS.

El problema es que a la hora de añadir el Apple Id, después de poner el usuario, la contraseña y el código SMS de verificación VisualStudio siempre dice "failed to synchronize account .... with Apple Developer portal. your session has expired. please log in"

Me parece extraño que me pide un código, que llega de inmediato y lo pongo, luego me pide otro que también me llega y lo pongo, para acabar diciendo que la sesión está expirada...

¿Alguna idea?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Tienes iniciada tu sesión de tu cuenta de Apple en Xcode?

Comment: Está configurada también en Xcode, pero el programa lo tengo cerrado. ¿Quito la cuenta de ahí?

Comment: Según el foro de Microsoft, es un problema actual que aún no tiene solución. Puedes revisar en este link https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/821901/cant-log-in-to-apple-developer-account-from-vs2019.html. El último comentario tiene fecha de ayer.

Comment: Mucha gracias Bicho, me voy a adherir al bug porque es exactamente lo que me pasa.